# Multiple HighCharts on different pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript, highcharts

I have a coffeescript:

```
chart = undefined
$ ->
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
  chart:
    renderTo: "sales "
    type: "line"
```

......

```
chart1 = undefined
$ ->
  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(
    chart:
      renderTo: "graph"
      type: "line"
```

.....

```
<div id="sales" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="graph" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

This works fine if both div's are on the same html-page, but not if I share each div on a different page.
I can't see a reason..why

Tha basic idea is to show different line charts on different pages.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are including the code for both charts on each page, you should be getting a javascript error - Highcharts Error 13 ( http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13 ).

This error happens when you tell Highcharts to build a chart in a div that does not exist.

This error will often stop the other chart(s) from being displayed.

You need to call only the charts that you have containing elements for on each page, and no others.